# React-Native — Promise setup e data handling

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise, fetch-api

I am trying to understand how developers use Promise with React-Native. It would be great to get feedback and recommendations on how to setup API calls and handle the data.  Please understand I never used Promise before and that I am new to React-Native.

Thank you in advance. Any resource about this subject is welcome too.

**Pseudocode**

Child

- Retrieve two variables
- Use these two variables to build an URL
- Trigger the first Promise and resolve
- Retrieve another two variables
- Use these two variables to build a new an URL
- Trigger the second Promise and resolve
- Gather the data from both promises and pass to parent

Parent

- Retrieve data from Child
- Get data from the first Promise and set to a state
- Get data from the second Promise and set to another state

**APIservice.js**

Child

Is it a good practice to setup all your API calls in a separate file? It's likely that in the future I will need to make different API calls, would you create multiple functions to handle that?

```
class APIservice {


    _getStopPoint = (endpoint) => {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            fetch(endpoint)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                console.log("APIservice StopPoint", data)
                resolve(data);
            });
        });
    };
};


module.exports = new APIservice
```

**App.js**

Parent

As you can see, the way I setup the endpoint is lame. It's not ideal as the URL is the same. I want to structure something that can receive two variables and build the URL on the go. Something like `https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/${routeid}/Arrivals/${stationid}`.

If I manage that, how can I pass the API call to the APIservice having only one `endpoint` that dynamically will change based on the two variables it receives? I am not sure how to differentiate the call in the `Promise.all` having only "one" URL.

That brings me another issue. When setting the state in App.js, should I setState using the specifics array from data? Something like `bus: data[0]`, `tube: data[1]`. Is this a good practice?

```
let APIservice = require('./APIservice')

let endpoint = 'https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/55/Arrivals/490004936E'
let endpoint1 = 'https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/Northern/Arrivals/940GZZLUODS'


let loadData = (endPoint) => {

  // Multiple API calls
  Promise.all([
    APIservice._getStopPoint(endpoint),
    APIservice._getStopPoint(endpoint1),
  ])
  .then((data) => {
    console.log("App.js", data)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  })
}

export default class App extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    // URL fetch based on variables, not dynamic
    loadData(endpoint)
    loadData(endpoint1)
  }

  render() {
    loadData("hello")
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>
          Promise
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You are asking many questions in the same post.  I would suggest you break them up into separate posts, with one question each.

Comment: Good idea. I just realised that.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this example

```
const callbackFn = (firstName, callback) => {
setTimeout(() => {
if (!firstName) return callback(new Error('no first name 
passed in!'))

const fullName = `${firstName} Doe`

return callback(fullName)
  }, 2000)
}

callbackFn('John', console.log)
callbackFn(null, console.log)
```